# Multiple np.where with reducing match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to create a column `Result` where the output will be one of the following 3 columns `code1`, `code2` or `code3` depending upon the condition if matches.

I created the below statement with `np.where`:

```
df['Result'] =  np.where((df.code == 'BTB.JPWK'), df.code_1, 
                np.where((df.code == 'BTB.JP'), df.code_2, 
                np.where((df.code == 'BTB.'), df.code_3, '1')))
```

But the output populated in the result is not correct. It always populates `1` which is false condition in complete iteration irrespective of the condition match.

I think i am missing the correct output because there might be a case where `df.code` will be matching all 3 conditions but i need to select only the best matched condition where most digits are matching.

I have a huge `data-set` so trying to find an easier method which will populate the result column properly without taking too much of time.

===========================================================================

After applying solution from @AkshayNevrekar I have tried performing modification:

I tried the below:

```
mask1 = [df.Cluster == 'Japan' , df.code_4 == 'BTB.JPWK']
mask2 = [df.Cluster == 'Japan' , df.code_5 == 'BTB.JP']
mask3 = [df.Cluster == 'Japan' , df.code_6 == 'BTB.']
mask4 = [df.Cluster == 'Japan' , df.code != 'BTB.']

df['Result'] = np.select([mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4],[df.code_1, df.code_2, df.code_3, df.code])
```

Here i get Value error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Dataframe is as follows:

```
Cluster code    Result
Japan   BTB.JP828802    828802
Japan   BTB.JP828804    828804
Japan   BTB.JP828806    828806
Japan   BTB.JPNS9002    NS9002
Japan   040615  040615
Japan   BTB.JP823045    823045
Japan   BTB.JPNS9001    NS9001
Japan   BTB.JPWK821517  821517
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have multiple condition use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead of [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
mask1 = df.code == 'BTB.JPWK'
mask2 = df.code == 'BTB.JP'
mask3 = df.code == 'BTB.'

df['Result'] = np.select([mask1, mask2, mask3],[df.code_1, df.code_2, df.code_3], 1)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Can you please explain the logic for this.How does this work?

Comment: Also, can i combine 2 conditions in mask assignment?

I tried the following but it is not working:

`mask1 = df.Cluster == 'Japan' & df.code == 'BTB.JPWK'`

Comment: yes you can add, mask is nothing but variable that will be storing True and False. Are you getting any error  or  what? Really difficult to say without looking at data

Comment: I was not able to format properly in comments so i have updated it in my question. You may please have a look and suggest if possible. thanks